# controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType: not always called when item added to database

Tags: ios, core-data

A colleague and I are working on a messaging program for iOS.  We store the messages using Core Data.  If I understand the way things are supposed to work, whenever a new message is stored in the database, because we have configured our app to work with NSFetchedResultsController, Core Data is supposed to tell our chat view controller what change has been made using the method controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:.  This works *most* of the time, but on some occasions said method does not fire.  This has been particularly noted when multiple messages are dealt with in rapid succession.  Even in said cases, controllerDidChangeContent: does fire, so Core Data does know something has happened.  Does anyone have any idea what’s going wrong?

Note:  I have devised a workaround in which whenever a new message is added to the database, an NSNotification of the addition is automatically posted; said notification is observed by the chat view controller and acted upon if appropriate.  This works without creating new problems.  However, my colleague is worried, because my solution subverts the way Apple intended us to handle database-view controller communication and thus might conceivably cause unexpected problems in the future.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

UPDATE (2017-04-27):  The code for the relevant predicate is:

```
//  The predicate needs to be as follows:
//  Select * WHERE (fromuser == userTelephoneNumber AND touser == friendTelephoneNumber) OR
//                 (fromuser == friendTelephoneNumber AND touser == userTelephoneNumber)

//  First condition
NSPredicate *chatFromMe   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromuser == %@", self.userTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatToFriend = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"touser == %@", self.friendTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatFromMeToFriend = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromMe, chatToFriend]];

//  Second condition
NSPredicate *chatFromFriend = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromuser == %@", self.friendTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatToMe       = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"touser == %@", self.userTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatFromFriendToMe = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromFriend, chatToMe]];

NSPredicate *totalCondition = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromMeToFriend, chatFromFriendToMe]];
```

Comment: What does your core-data stack look like?

Comment: What does the predicate of your NSFetchedResultsController look like? does it use relationships?

Comment: This is the description of our predicate:
        
    //  The predicate needs to be as follows:
    //  Select * WHERE (fromuser == userTelephoneNumber AND touser == friendTelephoneNumber) OR
    //                 (fromuser == friendTelephoneNumber AND touser == userTelephoneNumber)

Comment: This is the actual predicate code (part 1):
//   First condition
NSPredicate *chatFromMe   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromuser == %@", self.userTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatToFriend = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"touser == %@", self.friendTelephoneNumber];
    NSPredicate *chatFromMeToFriend = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromMe, chatToFriend]];

Comment: This is the actual predicate code (part 2):
//  Second condition
NSPredicate *chatFromFriend = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromuser == %@", self.friendTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatToMe       = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"touser == %@", self.userTelephoneNumber];
NSPredicate *chatFromFriendToMe = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromFriend, chatToMe]];

NSPredicate *totalCondition = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[chatFromMeToFriend, chatFromFriendToMe]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:totalCondition];

Comment: please update your original post with additional information rather than dumping it into the comments. This makes it easier for people trying to help provide an appropriate answer and also easier for people suffering a similar problem to learn from your experience.

Comment: What does your core data stack look like?  this can happen if the object being changed was not faulted at the time of the merged.

Answer (score 0):

NSFetchedResultsController will only react to -save: being called on the NSManagedObjectContext. So you may not see this method fire if you are not saving the newly created entity.

You have to re-fetch after a context change. So back to using the NSFetchedResultsController, you would do: - `(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]; [self.tableView reloadData]; }`

Also The general rule with Core Data is one Managed Object Context per thread, and one thread per MOC. With that in mind you need to perform the fetch for the Fetched Results Controller on the main thread, as this is the thread that will be interacting with the FRC's Managed Objects.